# trying to add a countdown timer to a maze game I already have in canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I have the maze game working but do not know how to add a timer to it. I want it to start from 60 seconds and when the time runs out it will display a game over message.The time will be shown decrementing above the game if possible. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) store the time when your game starts :

```
var startTime = Date.now();
```

(or store it in a property).

2) then, in your game loop :

```
var timeElapsed = Date.now() - startTime;
if (timeElapsed > 60000) {
    // ... game over code
}
// to display the time, do something like :
var timeElapsed_second = Math.floor (timeElapsed / 1000 );
displayTime(timeElapsed_second);
```